# jquery - form ajax database check for unique value

Tags: jquery, validation, pdo

using

- jquery validator plugin
- jquery

try to:

- make sure a username doesn't exist in the database

  - have a form + a field + remote check
  - i want to let jquery check using ajax if it exists.

what works:

- check-username.php does work by itself

what doesn't

- form doesn't seem to be able to pass return boolean value to validate the remote jquery validation
- how do I get it to pass the value so that the field can be validated?

**HTML**

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script language="javascript" src="validate.js"></script>

    <meta name="generator" content="" />
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
<body>

<form action="/" method="post" id="register-form">
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username<font color="red">*</font>:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="username" size="20" id="username" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQUERY Validate**

```
$().ready(function() {
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                remote: "check-username.php"
                },
        },
        messages: {
            username:{
                remote: "This username is already taken! Try another."
            },
        },
    });
});
```

**Check-USERNAME.php**

```
<?php

$searchVal = $_POST['username'];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$data", $username, $password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERNAME = " . "'" . $searchVal .  "'";
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   if($result>0){
     return true;
   }else {
     return false;
   }

    $dbh = null;
    }
        catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }       
?>
```

Comment: move `$dbh = null;` some rows up.

Comment: tried but the field doesn't check the db when duplicate value is entered.

Comment: That is not connected with your issue, but better to disconnect before `return`. Btw, I'm using [this](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) - very simple code for checking used names, etc.

Comment: i did look at that but don't see a clear example and was wondering was there a simpler way of doing it since the post was in 2009.

Comment: Do not mind the year, it is working pretty well. See my answer down.

Comment: check this post for answer
[Jquery-validator-check-for-existing-username][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539115/jquery-validator-plugin-check-for-existing-username-email-in-mysql-database/25397201#25397201

Answer (score 8):

In order to validate value to server side, you should add new Validation Method.

```
$().ready(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod("checkUserName", 
        function(value, element) {
            var result = false;
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                async: false,
                url: "check-username.php", // script to validate in server side
                data: {username: value},
                success: function(data) {
                    result = (data == true) ? true : false;
                }
            });
            // return true if username is exist in database
            return result; 
        }, 
        "This username is already taken! Try another."
    );

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: {
            "username": {
                required: true,
                checkUserName: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As stated above, method checkUserName will verify to server side and give error message "*This username is already taken! Try another.*" if username is not exist.

For more info and examples about jQuery Validation and its method : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392043/form-validation-a-standard-solution/17768847#17768847).

Hopefully this help.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't check the rest of your code, but try this:

```
<?php
    $searchVal = $_POST['username'];
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$data", $username, $password);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERNAME = " . "'" . $searchVal .  "'";
        $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($result>0) {
            $valid = "true";
        } else {
            $valid = "false";
        }

        $dbh = null;

        echo $value;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

?>

Comment: the php code already worked itself but for some reason I can't get jquery validator to see the validation value to validate the field.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using a different plugin from [here](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/).
For checking name availability using Ajax calls make following:

After downloading attach `jquery.validationEngine.js` and your locale like:

```
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Note, that `en` locale is also compulsory to be included.

Open and modify your language file, you have to point where is your `php` file which will check the database for name availability or to use default file name. So, find the following rows in `jquery.validationEngine-en.js` in case you use English.

```
 "ajaxUserCallPhp": {
    "url": "phpajax/ajaxValidateFieldUser.php",
```

Here you can change file name if you want like:

```
 "ajaxUserCallPhp": {
    "url": "my-file_which_will_check_db.php",
```

And your `my-file_which_will_check_db.php` should look like:

```
<?
/* RECEIVE VALUE */
$validateValue=$_REQUEST['fieldValue'];
$validateId=$_REQUEST['fieldId'];

$validateError= "This username is already taken";
$validateSuccess= "This username is available";

/* RETURN VALUE */
$arrayToJs = array();
$arrayToJs[0] = $validateId;

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass); //Connect with your credentials
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * From `users` WHERE `USERNAME` = '{$validateValue}'"); 
$dbh = null;                    // Disconnect

sleep(1); /*added because check is very fast and the label 'checking...' is not visible*/

if ($result = $stmt->fetch()) { 
$arrayToJs[1] = false;          // found user with that name
echo json_encode($arrayToJs);           
}
else {
$arrayToJs[1] = true;
echo json_encode($arrayToJs);       // that user name is free
}
?>
```

Finally, your HTML markup should look like:

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" class="validate[required],custom[onlyLetterNumber],maxSize[20],ajax[ajaxUserCallPhp] text-input" />
```

Note additional `class` attribute here.

And include following script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#register_form").validationEngine();
  });
</script>
```