# display error messages below fields

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to display error messages below the fields in my contact form. But Im not able to do so. Here is my code:-

contact.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){

$.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {   
 $('#success').html(response);
 //$('#success').hide('slow');
});
return false;


});

});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="mycontactform" class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Contact Us</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name"  name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required />
            <small class="errorText"><?php echo $error["name"]; ?></small>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
            <small class="errorText"><?php echo $error["email"]; ?></small>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message"  cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
            <small class="errorText"><?php echo $error["message"]; ?></small>
        </li>
<li>
            <input type="button"  class="submit" style="width:70px; text-align:center; height:30px; margin-left:200px; cursor:pointer"  value="SEND" id="submit" />


        </li><div id="success" style="color:red;"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

send.php

```
<?php

// Here we get all the information from the fields sent over by the form.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

    $to = 'babloopuneeth@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Message: '.$message;
    $headers = 'From: youremail@domain.com' . "\r\n";


  $error  = array(
    "name"    =>  "",
    "email"   =>  "",
    "message" =>  ""
  );

  $email  = ( isset( $_POST["email"] ) ) ? trim( $_POST["email"] ) : false;
  $name   = ( isset( $_POST["name"] ) ) ? trim( $_POST["name"] ) : false;
  $message  = ( isset( $_POST["message"] ) ) ? trim( $_POST["message"] ) : false;

  if ( !$emai ) {
    $error["email"] = "Email is required!";
  }
  if ( !$name ) {
    $error["name"] = "Name is required!";
  }
  if ( !$message ) {
    $error["message"] = "Message is required!";
  }

else { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
    echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
}
?>
```

I tried many other ways but its not working. I just want the error message to be displayed below each field if the field is empty, Plz help me..

Comment: `if ( !$emai ) {` should be `if ( !$email ) {`

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br>` after each input

Comment: Its not even displayed next to the field

Comment: ok. Have you tried jquery validation plugin? or you just want to validate the form data in your send.php file anyway?

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

it's jquery AJAX. so you can't display return message with `<?php echo $error["name"]; ?>` on your form page. You have to use javascript for displaying error messages.

Comment: I want error messages on the same page and without page refresh. So i cant use javascript

Comment: why you can't?
You use `$('#success').html(response);`, it's the same thing.

Looking your 'send.php', "response" can be a string (if the mail was sent) or an array if an error was detected.

You have to treat by javascript your response and after you can display your response where you want in your html page without refreshing page...

Comment: So can you plz help me with the code, I m a newbie to jquery and ajax

Comment: First make your array a json response like this : `json_encode($error);` on send.php
Second you have to know if your response is an array like this : `if($.isArray(response))`, if it's an array, you have to treat in a different way. After adding an ID on every LI on your form HTML, you can display message error like this : `$("li#email .errorText").html(response.email)`. Use `console.log(response)` to know what is returned by your file send.php, you can see it in your console in the develpment tool in your browser (F12 on Chrome)

Comment: And that too i want error messages too be displayed below each field and success message below the form. How can i do this?

Comment: Sorry im not able to understand what exactly i should do?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){  

$('#submit').click(function(){  

$.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {  
if($.isArray(response)){  

if( typeof response["email"] != "undefined" ) {  
$("li#email .errorText").html(response["email"]);  
}  
/*you have to do that for every fields */

} else {  
 $('#success').html(response);  
}  
});  
return false;  

  
});
  
});`  
you have to do something like that..

Comment: Thanks what changes I have to make in my html form??

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery AJAX in order to retrieve server-side validation. [Here is the material](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Just for information, it's better to use jQuery Validation to validate form. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392043/form-validation-a-standard-solution/17768847#17768847) for light and thorough examples. You could adapt the code to your case.