# How can I validate for a unique email address?

Tags: php, ajax

I was trying to have my form validate an email address onblur or onkeyup, to check to see if the email address already exists in my database.

Not sure if I'm almost there with this code, something isn't working though. Right now, as soon as I start typing in the field, the input box for email is flagged based on how I would want it flagged if an email address was entered if it was already in my database. The else statement in AJAX doesn't work, and if I submit the form anyway, I get a message on the page from an error box I created mentioning a syntax error.

Also, part of my php is using mysqli and mysql, does that make a difference with trying to get this input field to validate?

The input id is email and the name is Email; I think I have that correct in my code, not entirely sure though.

PHP:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'host');

$first = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['First']));
$last = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Last']));
$city = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['City']));
$state = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['State']));
$country = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Country']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));
$tempt = $_POST['tempt'];
$tempt2 = $_POST['tempt2'];


$link = mysqli_connect('host','user','password','members') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE email =?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['Email']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
/* bind result variables */
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $count);
/* fetch value */
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

if ($count == 0) {
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}


if ($tempt == 'http://' && empty($tempt2)) {

    $error_message = '';
    $reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9­-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$/";

    if(!preg_match($reg_exp, $email)) {

        $error_message .= "<p>A valid email address is required.</p>";
    }
    if (empty($first)) {
        $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your first name.</p>";
    }
    if (empty($last)) {
        $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your last name.</p>";
    }
```

AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    if (valid != '') {
    $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('error2')
        .html('' +valid).fadeIn('fast');
}

    var valid = '';

    $('#email').keyup(function() {
        $.post('script.php', { 'Email' : $(this).val() }, function(data) {
             if(data !== 'true') {
                $('#email').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
                $('#email').css('background-color','#ffcece');
                valid += '<p>This email has already subscribed.</p>';
             }else{
                $('#email').css('background-color','green');
             }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please show only the relevant code? Just dumping all of your code is a great way to have your question ignored. Are you trying to do this check via AJAX or on form submit?

Comment: Yes, you use AJAX to execute a PHP script on the server that queries the database and returns matches.

Comment: thatidiotguy, I left out some php code, but I wasn't sure which was relevant for AJAX. I'm trying to do the check on both form submit and on keyup. So, if the form is submitted, the email address would be validated. If the form is not submitted, but an email address is typed in an input field, it can be checked that way as well.

Comment: You're making it hard to help you, it's not really clear what you need since you already have some code that seems to be doing what you want in a way. Just guessing at this point, maybe you just need to query your database at the error checking part?

Comment: Question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539115/jquery-validator-plugin-check-for-existing-username-email-in-mysql-database