# How to avoid or disable form submission when there are validation errors using Jquery Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-ui

I am actually facing an issue with my form validation using JQUERY Validator. The form is getting submitted even though it has validation errors on the fields. I am not sure how can we disable or not allow to submit form when there are validation errors on the fields? I believe bootstrap validator disables the button when there are validation errors. Though in my case I am using JQUERY VALIDATOR, so the form is being submitted and invoking an ajax call which i am invoking on submit. Please help!

```
form id="myform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="processAccount" method="post">
                    <h2><b style="color:#1E90FF;">Account</b></h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Account Number" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Account Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" id="accountNumber"  name="accountNumber" placeholder="Account Number" class="form-control" autofocus required />
                        <!--<span class="help-block">Last Name, First Name, eg.: Smith, Harry</span>-->                    
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Company Number" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Company Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" min="1" id="companyNumber" name="companyNumber" placeholder="Company Number" class="form-control" value=${companyNumber} required />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
    <!--                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="doAjaxPost()">Search</button>
     -->                        
                            <input type="button" style=" font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;  font-family: cursive;" id="processbutton" class="btn btn-info btn-block" value="Load" onclick="doAjaxPost()">

                                <div id="info" style="color: green; font-weight: bold;" font-size:380%;></div>      

    <%--                        <p ><strong>${message}</strong></p>
     --%>                                    
                        </div>
                      </div>

                </form> <!-- /form -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin

        rules: {
            accountNumber: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7,
                maxlength: 7,
                digits: true

            },
            companyNumber: {
                required: true,
                digits: true

            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                console.log("Submitted!");
                form.submit();
            }
        }
    });

});

    </script>



<script type="text/javascript">
function doAjaxPost() {  
      // get the form values  
      var accountNumber = $('#accountNumber').val();
      var companyNumber = $('#companyNumber').val();
      var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
      var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
      var num = 1;
      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "./processAccount",  
       cache: false, 
        data: "accountNumber=" + accountNumber + "&companyNumber=" + companyNumber,  
       beforeSend: function(xhr) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
       },
        success: function(response){  
          // we have the response  
          $('#info').html(response);
          $('#accountNumber').val('');
          if(companyNumber!=1)
              {
          $('#companyNumber').val(num);
              }
        },  
        error: function(e){  
          alert('Error While Request: ' + e);  
        }  
      });  
    }  
</script>
```

Added SubmitHandler method under the JQUERY Validation block, However getting an error as  Request method 'POST' not supported

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
                console.log("Submitted!");
                // get the form values  
              var accountNumber = $('#accountNumber').val();
              var companyNumber = $('#companyNumber').val();
              var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
              var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
              var num = 1;
              $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "./processAccount",  
              dataType: "json",
              contentType: 'application/json',
               cache: false, 
                data: "accountNumber=" + accountNumber + "&companyNumber=" + companyNumber,  
               beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                     xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
                 },
                success: function(response){  
                  // we have the response  
                  $('#info').html(response);
                  $('#accountNumber').val('');
                  if(companyNumber!=1)
                      {
                  $('#companyNumber').val(num);
                      }
                },  
                error: function(e){  
                  alert('Error While Request: ' + e);  
                }  
              }); 
              form.submit();
            }
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: your code is not proper format ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the submit button to `type="submit"` and remove the on click handler.

If you want to send it via AJAX you can still do that in the `submitHandler` callback.

Explanation: With setting your click handler to `doAjaxPost()` you're probably bypassing your validation and the `submitHandler` code gets never executed.

Additionally you have another error. `submitHandler` should be a sibbling of `rules` and not a child! It won't get called the way you use it. Use it like that instead:

```
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    submitHandler: function (form) {
         console.log("Submitted!");
         form.submit(); // default form submitting
    },
    rules: {
        accountNumber: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 7,
            maxlength: 7,
            digits: true
        },
        companyNumber: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
        }
    }
});
```

See also at the API documentation https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

For sending it via AJAX you should be able to call your `doAjaxPost()` instead of `form.submit();` - at this place the validation already happened.

EDIT: As whished from the OP - here how to write it with his custom AJAX call:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
      console.log("Submitted!");
      doAjaxPost(); // custom AJAX call
}
```

Comment: So you mean calling the doAjaxPost() function inside the submitHandler?                                                                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                console.log("Submitted!"); doAjaxPost();
                form.submit();
            }

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea. Could you post your doAjaxPost?

Comment: Sure..I just posted doAjaxPost() above

Comment: I extended my answer with another error I found and how to handle the sending via AJAX

Comment: Thanks Mike for your suggestion. I tried by adding the ajax code inside the submit handler function under the validation block and I am getting the following error message                                                                       Request method 'POST' not supported                                                              I have uploaded the code snippet above

Comment: @sam I think you should start a new question. The problem with the validation should definitely be solved with my suggestions - I tested it.

Comment: As a tip: I would try the AJAX call without all the validation script. Maybe you have problems with that too.

Comment: Ajax call works perfect there was an never issue with that. Only issue was with the jquery validation :(.

Comment: In your updated question you use the AJAX call besides form.submit(). As I said you should use it instead. It will not work like that. Remove the line with form.submit(). And no need to copy the function into submitHandler. You can just call
submitHandler: function (form) { 
  console.log('Submitted!');
  doAjaxPost();
}

Comment: Seeing your current code in a JSFiddle or similar would definitely help.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike!!!! You are correct I was making a stupid mistake by calling form.submit() and doAjaxPost() together so after removing form.submit() it worked like a charm..I highly appreciate your help so as all the other responders...:)

Comment: I have checked mark your answer. However, I would recommend you to edit and remove form.submit in your code snippet above so that would be benefit to others in the future..Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that doAjaxPost() method is called apart from validation result. Whats inside this method?

Could you identify jquery validate plugin your'er using (project page, documentation page...)?

Comment: I am making a backend call to validate the data against the DB

Comment: You can handle validation result inside your doAjaxPost() method before you do the call. Use  [.valid()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) if returns true cancel ajax request. Solution posted by @I'm Blue Da Ba Dee should also do the job.

Comment: One more thing: If you what to validate against db make it a part of validation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539115/jquery-validator-plugin-check-for-existing-username-email-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this way, just add this options:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  success: function() {
    $("button[type='submit']").prop("disabled",false);//enable your submit if success
  },
  invalidHandler: function(){
   $("button[type='submit']").prop("disabled",true); // disable your submit if there is any errors
    return false; //Disable post
  }
});
```

More Information https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/